# MVC3 ValidationSummary(No) not suppressing detail errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC3 razor form where I use 
  @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

It displays all errors including field errors at the top but it also displays field errors at field level. Is there a way to display at top only

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the Html.ValidationMessageFor(...) lines. These are the inline validation messages and are unrelated to ValidationSummary.

**Edit:** Making it optional:

```
@{var bool bInline = true;}
@Html.ValidationSummary(bInline)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyField)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyField)
@if (bInline)
{
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MyField)
}
```

Comment: Hi I need to make it optional- clients may want it at detail or summary level